# My C code breaks in a "realloc" func at the second run of the LOOP

Tags: c, memory-management

it breaks on this line (that in the for loop) ONLY IN THE SECOND RUN OF THE PROGREM:
 *(arrP + i) = (char*)realloc( (*arrP + i) ,  (sizeof( char ) * currentLen));

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf( "Please enter the amount of friends u have: \n\n \t" );
    unsigned int friendsNum = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &friendsNum );
    getchar();

    char** arrP = (char**)calloc( friendsNum, sizeof( char* ) );// pointer to a pointer array, that every item points on a str[0]
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int currentLen = 0;
    unsigned const int BUFFER = 28; // The maximum length you expect
    for (i = 0; i < friendsNum; i++)
    {
        *(arrP + i) = (char*)calloc( BUFFER, sizeof( char ) );
        if (!(arrP + i))
        {
            printf( "ERROR, EXITING" );
            return(1);
        }
        fgets( *(arrP + i), 20, stdin );
        (*(arrP + i))[strcspn( *(arrP + i), "\n" )] = '\0';
        currentLen = strlen( *(arrP + i) ) + 1;// including \0(+1)
        *(arrP + i) = (char*)realloc( (*arrP + i) ,  (sizeof( char ) * currentLen));
        if (!(arrP + i))
        {
            printf( "ERROR, EXITING" );
            return(1);
        }
    }


    getchar();  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont know why it changed the post but the line the code breakes goes like this:
        *(arrP + i) = (char*)realloc( (*arrP + i) ,  (sizeof( char ) * currentLen));
with stars before brekets..

Comment: `calloc`ing an array you initialise explicitly is useless. `malloc` is sufficient. And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! Also compiler warnings are not just fancy progress reports! Pay heed to them!

Comment: Presumably you need to change `(*arrP + i)` to `*(arrP + i)`.  But instead of writing `*(arrP+i)`, it's better to just write `arrP[i]`, which is completely equivalent.  That way you won't have bugs like this.

Comment: So I should just switch the callocs to mallocs?

Comment: You should get it to work first, *then* worry about optimizations like changing `calloc` to `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `*(arrP + i)` is not the same as `(*arrP + i)`:

- The first expression is equivalent to `arrP[i]`
- The second expression is equivalent to `arrP[0]+i`

You would have easier code if you switch to subscript-based access with `[]` operator instead of pointer arithmetics:

```
arrP[i] = realloc(arrP[i], currentLen);
```

Note that you do not cast `malloc` in C, and you can rely on the fact that `sizeof(char)` is required by the standard to be constant `1`.